# is it possible to use allure to handle TestStack/White results?

Tags: allure

We use https://github.com/TestStack/White for Windows Desktop app testing:

1) is it possible to use allure to handle test results?
2) is it possible to feed array with 20 test results file to allure to get one report?

Answer (score 0):

White is just a wrapper of MS UI Automation for easier interaction and access of UI Elements.

Use NUnit for C#, add allure plugin for it.
[Allure NUnit github](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure-nunit2)